# jstree detect multiple items being moved

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview, jstree

Using [jstree](https://www.jstree.com) is it possible to detect whether multiple selected nodes are being moved at the same time... or which of the nodes is currently being processed?  (You can select multiple nodes using the <kbd>shift</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> keys.)

I'm using the `move_node.jstree` event, but I can't see anything obvious in the `e` or `data` properties that can tell me if more than one item is being moved, or what index the node passed to the event is in the list.

```
$tree.bind("move_node.jstree", function (e, data) { ... }
```

Every time a node is moved from one parent node to another parent node, I need to call AJAX... which results in some processing on the server.

If multiple nodes are moved at the same time, there is simply no point doing this processing on the server for each individual node... it only makes sense to run the AJAX on the **last** node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Drag and drop plugin(dnd) for jsTree, the "move_node.jstree" is triggered for each individual nodes that are moved. Since the event is triggered for each node, multiple items being moved cannot be detected. You could however use the dnd plugin's event to detect multiple items being moved.

```
$(document).on("dnd_move.vakata", function (e, data) {
    console.log("DND Move"); //Triggered continuously during drag 
}).bind("dnd_stop.vakata", function(e, data) { //Triggered on drag complete
    console.log("Stop dnd");
    console.log("Nodes being moved: "+ data.data.nodes);
});

oTree.bind("move_node.jstree", function (e, data) { 
    console.log("Move Event");
});
```

The "dnd_stop.vakata" event is triggered before the move_node events and could be helpful. You would have to glue them all together though to make a single AJAX call.

Comment: Excellent idea - will try implementing and get back to you